# What is the best way to return a projected query to add filter afterward

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I need to make a query that return all items with the current price and the current reduction if any.

I tried a few solutions but none seem to work or respect the patterns as i understand them.

The dynamic solution:
I tried to return the data as a dynamic that would be an IQueryable where T would be (Item, CurrentItemPrice, CurrentItemStateIfAny)

```
    public ItemRepository(CoconutEntities context) : base(context){}   

    public dynamic GetAllCurrentItems(){
        var items = (from item in context.Items
                    select new { 
                        Item = item, 
                        CurrentItemPrice = item.ItemPrices.Where(x => item.ItemPrices.Max(y => y.EffectiveDate) == x.EffectiveDate),
                        CurrentItemState = item.ItemReductions.Where(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now <= x.EndDate)});

        return items;
    }
```

But when i try this and i need to add filter, i can't add them the way i was expecting.

```
    public dynamic GetCurrentItems(string filter = "", int categoryId = 1) {
        dynamic result;

        var categoryServices = new CategoryServices();

        IEnumerable<int> categoryIdAndChildCategoriesId = categoryServices.GetCategoryIdAndChildsId(categoryId);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
        {
            result = this.GetAllCurrentItems().Where(x => ((string)(x.Item.Name)) == filter);
        }
        else if(categoryId != 1)
        {
            result = this.GetAllCurrentItems().Where(x => x.Item.ItemCategories.Any(x => categoryIdAndChildCategoriesId.Contains(x.CategoryId)));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Solution 2 : I also tried with Tuple where i should have been able to do somthing like this but i can't create Tuples from Linq to Entities if i understood in an other post. I would need to query all the item first, then use linq to object to create my tuples.

Solution 3 : I can create a viewmodel or a new model that would represent the data i need. I know this would work but i don't understand where it would stand between the two. If it is not a view model, this information won't go to the view it an other way to see an item with only the current information. 
In short, there are probably many solutions to this problem, but i need help to understand which solution would be the best and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you you want to do as much as possible on the database - that is good. You might achieve that with tuples like that:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<Item,decimal, decimal>> GetAllCurrentItems(Expression<Func<Item, bool>> filterExpression){
    using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        var items = context.Items
                .Where(filterExpression)
                .Select(item => new Tuple<Item,decimal, decimal> ( 
                    item, 
                    item.ItemPrices.Where(x => item.ItemPrices.Max(y => y.EffectiveDate) == x.EffectiveDate),
                    item.ItemReductions.Where(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && DateTime.Now <= x.EndDate)});

        return items;
    }
}
```

And calling it like that:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<Item,decimal, decimal>> GetCurrentItems(string filter = "", int categoryId = 1) {
    dynamic result;

    var categoryServices = new CategoryServices();

    IEnumerable<int> categoryIdAndChildCategoriesId = categoryServices.GetCategoryIdAndChildsId(categoryId);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
    {
        result = this.GetAllCurrentItems(x => ((string)(x.Item.Name)) == filter);
    }
    else if(categoryId != 1)
    {
        result = this.GetAllCurrentItems(x => x.Item.ItemCategories.Any(x => categoryIdAndChildCategoriesId.Contains(x.CategoryId)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, yes i am trying to do as much job on the server as possible. And reduce the number of query required.